# Gradient flows when there are two directions of steepest descent

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, gradient-flows, non-smooth-analysis, non-smooth-optimization

Loosely speaking, a gradient flow

$$ \dot{x}(t) = - \nabla E(x(t)),\quad x(0) = x_0 $$

says that the trajectory of $x$ is evolving in the direction of steepest descent of some functional $E$ (usually called an energy functional). Here I keep things $\textbf{general}$, and do not assume $x$ to be in Euclidean space (i.e., $\nabla$ may not be the Euclidean gradient).

The idea is captured in the following image:

[image: General Gradient Flow Image]

Is it possible for a trajectory to reach a point in which there are multiple directions of steepest descent of the functional $E$, and if so which direction will it choose to go in?

Comment: That would be a subgradient flow...

Comment: So your function $E$ is not differentiable in the usual sense.

Comment: Thanks guys, I see now... silly question. @RodrigodeAzevedo are such things studied much ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_inclusion